# Как равномерно разместить в блоке списки разной длины?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой при выводе разного количества списков в блоке, по типу мега-меню, есть примерно такая конструкция

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-menu>ul {
  width: 100%;
}

ul.level-2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.nav-menu__item.level-1 {
  display: inline-nlock;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.nav-menu__item.level-1:hover>ul.level-2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-menu__item level-1">
      <a href="/">меню 1</a>
      <ul class="level-2">
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-menu__item level-1">
      <a href="/">меню 1</a>
      <ul class="level-2">
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Нужно что бы элементы адаптировались под высоту блока, примерно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

важно что бы они переносились на другую строку только если не помещаются по высоте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как такое можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `flexbox`.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-menu>ul {
  width: 100%;
}

ul.level-2 {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.nav-menu__item.level-1 {
  display: inline-nlock;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.nav-menu__item.level-1:hover>ul.level-2 {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-menu__item level-1">
      <a href="/">меню 1</a>
      <ul class="level-2">
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-menu__item level-1">
      <a href="/">меню 1</a>
      <ul class="level-2">
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-menu__item level-2">
          <a href="/">подменю 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu__item level-3">
              <a href="/">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```